# Websphere Application Server : what is com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher

Tags: websphere

In IBM Websphere Application Server (WAS) what are the purpose of com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher and com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher? Every morning we are restarting the Websphere Application Server. So on the stat of WAS it will always be called to load applications war file? Or there are certain action on which these two are used by WAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSPreLauncher and WSLauncher are main entry points in the starting the OSGi framework and server processes.  If you look at startServer script, you'll see it invokes the WSLauncher class with a number of additional arguments that are essential to proper server startup.  To your question, when using the serverStart script, WSLauncher will be called and as a part of starting all the components of the server, applications, including war files, may be started depending on your specific configuration.  You should not invoke either the WSPreLauncher or WSLauncher entry points yourself and instead should use the provided scripts like startServer, startNode, etc.